# Why does R update function changes glmer fit when called with 1 argument?

Tags: r, scope

Below is a simplified code reproducing what looks to me like a problem with R `update` function:

```
library('lme4')
f <- function(formula) {
  data <- data.frame(a = c(4, 5), rowi = c(1, 2), b = c(2, 2))
  fit0 <- glmer(formula, data = data, family = poisson(log))
  fit1 <- update(fit0)
  cat('f likelihoods: ', logLik(fit0), logLik(fit1), '\n')
}
g <- function() {
  f(a ~ -1 + (1|rowi) + offset(b))
  data <- data.frame(a = c(4, 5), rowi = c(1, 2), b = c(20, 40))
  f(a ~ -1 + (1|rowi) + offset(b))
  cat('g likelihood: ', logLik(glmer(a ~ -1 + (1|rowi) + offset(b),
      data = data, family = poisson(log))), '\n')
}
g()
data <- data.frame(a = c(4, 5), rowi = c(1, 2), b = c(50, 80))
g()
cat('global likelihood: ', logLik(glmer(a ~ -1 + (1|rowi) + offset(b),
    data = data, family = poisson(log))), '\n')
```

This code outputs:

```
f likelihoods:  -4.712647 -4.712647 
f likelihoods:  -4.712647 -12.6914 
g likelihood:  -12.6914 
f likelihoods:  -4.712647 -14.22997 
f likelihoods:  -4.712647 -12.6914 
g likelihood:  -12.6914 
global likelihood:  -14.22997
```

The surprising (to me) thing is that `update(fit0)` operation changes the model when `data` is defined in the environment of the formula. Why is that? How to use `update` properly to avoid pitfalls like this?

Comment: `update()` is delicate (more delicate than it should be). Not sure how soon I'll be able to get to this, but have posted a link at https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/416 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this, too. The short answer is that `update.merMod(model)` employs `environment(formula(model))` to determine which environment to use when refitting the model (if that fails, then it'll try the enclosing environment, and so on). The result is that `update()` refits the model using the environment that the formula was created in, *not* the environment that the original `merMod` object was created in. This is consistent with the behavior of the example you cooked up.

My clumsy way around this issue would be to pass the formulas around as strings, and be sure to convert to formulas inside the same function body where the model is originally fit; e.g.

```
f <- function(formula_string) {
  formula <- as.formula(formula_string)
  data <- data.frame(a = c(4, 5), rowi = c(1, 2), b = c(2, 2))
  fit0 <- glmer(formula, data = data, family = poisson(log))
  fit1 <- update(fit0)
  cat('f likelihoods: ', logLik(fit0), logLik(fit1), '\n')
}
g <- function() {
  f("a ~ -1 + (1|rowi) + offset(b)")
  data <- data.frame(a = c(4, 5), rowi = c(1, 2), b = c(20, 40))
  f("a ~ -1 + (1|rowi) + offset(b)")
  cat('g likelihood: ', logLik(glmer(a ~ -1 + (1|rowi) + offset(b),
      data = data, family = poisson(log))), '\n')
}
```

I'm not sure if the current behavior is desirable for some reason (that's a question for @benbolker and the other `lme4` developers), or what a lower-level fix might look like ... aside from either explicitly setting/saving the environment of the `merMod` object at creation, or a recursive frame search that uses `identical()` (ala `where()` in `pryr`). There are probably good arguments against these.