# lme4 allFit() giving confusing results when wrapped in a function

Tags: r, lme4

I am using `allFit()` in lme4 to automatically scan through possible optimizers, since the default optimizer usually doesn't converge in this situation. My code works fine when I run `it line-by-line`, but when I run it wrapped in a simple function, it gives different results.

I've looked at the output of the allFit call and it seems that when it's NOT inside the function, it returns a list of `lmerModLmerTest` objects as desired.

However, inside the function, it returns a list with the values `simpleError`, `error`, and `condition`. Why is it doing this?

I'm using RStudio, R 3.6, lme4 1.1-21, lmerTest 3.1-0.

**UPDATE: The problem is that the update() method used by allFit cannot find the 'tt' data frame when re-fitting the models. I have put breakpoints into the code and it seems that the 'test' data exists in the function environment, however, so I don't understand why it can't find it...**

**UPDATE 2: It appears that if I change the assignment of the test data to `<<-`, it works. This is dangerous, though, by breaking functional programming, and I think it may fail when I try to parallelize. I am testing further... still open to suggestions!**

Here is the code that works, not inside the function:

```
library(lme4)

multi_arm_var_sim <- function(nsub = 20, nclust = 100, narm = 2, iccs = c(.01, .04), betas = c(0,.3)){
  sig_b2 <- -1*iccs / (iccs - 1)
  n <- nsub * nclust * narm
  y <- rep_len(NA, n)
  arm <- as.factor(rep(0:(narm-1), each = nsub*nclust))
  clustid <- rep(1:(nclust*narm), each = nsub)
  clustRElist <- rnorm(narm*nclust, mean = 0, sd = rep(sqrt(sig_b2), each = nclust))
  clustRE <- rep(clustRElist, each = nsub)
  sig_b2 <- rep(sig_b2, each = nclust*nsub)
  error <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  beta <- rep(betas, each = nclust*nsub)
  linpred <- beta + clustRE + error
  output <- cbind.data.frame(arm, clustid, sig_b2, clustRE, linpred)
  return(output)
}

set.seed(2)
test_1 <- multi_arm_var_sim()
model_flex_1 <- lmer(linpred ~ arm + (1 + arm | clustid),
                             data = test_1)

diff_optims_1 <- allFit(model_flex_1, verbose = TRUE)
print(class(diff_optims_1[[1]]))
is.OK_1 <- sapply(diff_optims_1, is, "lmerMod")
print(is.OK_1)
```

And here is the code that doesn't work, same setup, wrapped in a function.

```
library(lme4)

multi_arm_var_sim <- function(nsub = 20, nclust = 100, narm = 2, iccs = c(.01, .04), betas = c(0,.3)){
  sig_b2 <- -1*iccs / (iccs - 1)
  n <- nsub * nclust * narm
  y <- rep_len(NA, n)
  arm <- as.factor(rep(0:(narm-1), each = nsub*nclust))
  clustid <- rep(1:(nclust*narm), each = nsub)
  clustRElist <- rnorm(narm*nclust, mean = 0, sd = rep(sqrt(sig_b2), each = nclust))
  clustRE <- rep(clustRElist, each = nsub)
  sig_b2 <- rep(sig_b2, each = nclust*nsub)
  error <- rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
  beta <- rep(betas, each = nclust*nsub)
  linpred <- beta + clustRE + error
  output <- cbind.data.frame(arm, clustid, sig_b2, clustRE, linpred)
  return(output)
}

get_pval <- function(){
  tt <- multi_arm_var_sim()
  model_flex <- lme4::lmer(linpred ~ arm + (1 + arm | clustid),
                               data = tt)
  diff_optims <- lme4::allFit(model_flex, data = tt, verbose = TRUE)
  print(class(diff_optims[[1]]))
  is.OK <- sapply(diff_optims, is, "merMod")
  print(is.OK)
}
set.seed(2)
get_pval()
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Does setting `set.seed(2)` in front of `get_pval()` change anything?

Comment: No... same error either way.

Comment: this is peripherally related to https://github.com/lme4/lme4/issues/514 . The issue is that `allFit()` uses `update()`, which re-evaluates the function call in the current environment.  I'm a little bit put off by the wall of code above (not necessarily your fault ...), but my general approach would be to try to make sure that the data are copied into the appropriate environment ...

Comment: Thanks Ben. I have tried to slim down the code to make it a bit clearer in this example. The data 'tt' is being created within the function, so doesn't it just exist in the get_pval function environment? And since update() is called within the function, shouldn't it look in the get_pval function environment for 'tt'? EDIT: Reading up on the github issues you referenced helps. I'll see if I can use the workaraound here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43671203/why-does-r-update-function-changes-glmer-fit-when-called-with-1-argument

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Can't seem to get update() to use the proper environment, even if the formula is created within the get_pval function.